Discord JS v14 Bot Script Not Working (Specifically, GuildCreate and GuildMemberAdd not triggering)
Okay. I've tried everything I can think of here, and I can't seem to find anything that is a similar problem to mine. The closest thing might be this post.
I'm trying to build a Discord bot that can detect how recently a user created their account, immediately after they join the server. There have been lots of problems with people creating alternate accounts to bypass bans, and the goal is to more easily identify these people.
At it's simplest form, the bot needs to detect A: When another user joins the guild, and B: When it is added to a guild. I've set my permissions properly, as far as I can tell; yet the GuildCreate and GuildMemberAdd events are NOT triggered at all. No logging or anything.
My script was originally taken from another bot I built back in November~January or so. Really the only thing I kept from it was the command loader, since it worked decently for me.
I've left the code for my events, to highlight my purpose with the bot, but really if anyone can provide a solution that allows the first line of the events to be logged I'll be more than happy.
EDIT:
I should also add, that my bot starts successfully and I can execute its commands in the server. But it doesn't appear in the member list, or in the member list on any channels. All of them are open to everyone.
Here is my code:
const { token, clientId } = require('./config.json');
const { Client, Collection, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9');
const { Database } = require('./components/Database.js');

// Create a new client instance
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildPresences,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildVoiceStates, // For voice states
        GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent // For content in messages
  ],
});

// Create a collection to store command files
client.commands = new Collection();

// Function to recursively read command files from the 'commands' directory
async function readCommandFiles(dir) {
    const files = await fs.promises.readdir(dir);

    for (const file of files) {
       const filePath = path.join(dir, file);
        const stat = await fs.promises.stat(filePath);
  
        if (stat.isDirectory()) {
            await readCommandFiles(filePath);
        }
        else if (file.endsWith('.js')) {
            console.log("File: " + filePath);
            const command = require('./' + filePath);
            if (command.data == undefined) { // No specified command data
                continue;
            }
            client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
        }
    }
}

async function refresh_guild(GuildID) {
    // Update the server-side commands
    try {
        console.log('Started refreshing guild commands.');

        await rest.put(
            Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId, GuildID),
            { body: client.commands.map(command => command.data.toJSON()) },
        );

        console.log('Successfully reloaded guild commands.');
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.error('Error while refreshing guild commands:', error);
    }
}

async function reload() {
    // Get ALL watchlists
    let tables = await db.get('watchlist', 'guild', 'guild', '*');

    // Read the command files
    await readCommandFiles('commands');

    // Refresh ALL guild commands
    for (let table of tables) {
        await refresh_guild(table.guild);
    }
}

// Create the watchlist database
const db = new Database('./watchlist.db');

// Set the REST API version
const rest = new REST({ version: '9' }).setToken(token);

// When the client is ready, run this code (only once)
// Adds and enables commands in the server
client.once('ready', async () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
    
    // Reload the server-side commands
    await reload();
});

client.on('guildCreate', async (guild) => {
    console.log("I don't freaking work!")
    console.log(`Joined a new guild: ${guild.name} (ID: ${guild.id})`);
    
    // Create the watchlist table for the guild
    let table = db.createIfAbsent('watchlist', ['time', 'unit', 'log_channel', 'guild'])
    .then(() => {})
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });

    await refresh_guild(guild.id);
});

client.on('guildDelete', (guild) => {
    console.log('Guess who doesn\'t work... Meeeeeeeeeee! ')
    console.log(guild);
})

client.on('guildMemberAdd', async (member) => {
    console.log("Still not effing working!");

    // Wait for the watchlist table
    let watchlist = await db.get('watchlist', '*', 'guild', (member.guild.id + ''));

    console.log(watchlist);

    // Get the first table
    watchlist = watchlist[0];

    if (watchlist.log_channel == undefined) {
        console.warn("Error: LOG CHANNEL NOT FOUND")
        return;
    }
    
    // Figure out if the admins should be notified
    
    // Get the watchlist channel
    const log_channel = member.guild.channels.cache.get(watchlist.log_channel);
    
    // The channel doesn't work
    if (!log_channel) {
        throw new Error("LogChannelError: The log channel doesn't seem to exist!");
    }
    
    // Record any suspicious members in the watchlist channel
});

const interaction = require('./events/interactionCreate.js');

client.on(interaction.event, interaction.execute);
console.log(client.login(token).then((stuff) => {
    console.log("Logged In");
    return(stuff);
}).catch((error) => { console.log(error) }));

module.exports = {
    client
}

I appreciate the help.

Guilds intent is missing.
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, // <- Add
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildPresences,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildVoiceStates, // For voice states
        GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent // For content in messages
  ],
});

